# How much food does a person need each year?

Tags: banished

I've got some pretty poorly performing fisheries. Can't quite explain why (they're not overlapping and the workers live right next to them), but they only produce about 200food/year for 4 people. I think this is way under what's required so I'm planning to go destroying the underperforming fisheries.

How much food does a person need each year? This way I can know which fisheries are at least subsistence-level and which are not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using the Town Hall statistics, you can see how much food your population is consuming (and producing) each year. As far as how much EACH person needs a year, you can divide Used over the last year by total population to get an estimate. It's not exact, because people are born / die during the year so the population number fluctuates, but I get just over 100 food per citizen using this method.

To access the Town Hall statistics, build a town hall, click on it, and select the Production tab.

[image: Food per year]

Comment: Also note that even if they consume 100 food per year, the amount of stored food might fluctuate by more than that, because they like to stockpile / hoard food in their houses. So if you have 100 population, they should eat 10,000 food, but the first 75 citizens might take 10k food into their homes leaving none for the other citizens.

Comment: Ended up using exactly this tool to determine exactly the same answer. Then saw this post. Excellent answer.